# Overheating iMac(2008) with kubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, fan, kubuntu

I have an 24 inch iMac from 2008 and I installed Kubuntu 12.04 on it. The problem is:
if I' m running and CPU-hungry program(Android Emulator, Virtual Box), the CPU goes to 80C. Also the screen is very hot. How can I increase the fan speed?(I tried fancontrol package, but pwmconfig tells me that there aren't any pwm-capable fans. Also , I tried to find the special file in `/sys/devices/platform` but I couldn't find anything that worked)
So, what to do?

Comment: Does the same or similar happen under a Live-System of 12.10 or 13.04? Any BIOS settings which might be wrong?

Comment: Def try the latest Ubuntu distibution. There is a newer kernel version in new Ubuntu and that new kernel may support the features that'll help you with your issue.